# sonar doesn't show up code coverage

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, maven-2, sonarqube

I configure sonar with jenkins,i build the maven project in jenkins it builds successfully but in sonar always shows code coverage blank.[image] what can be problem please help me....

this is sonar dashboard.
code coverage

Comment: are your tests in the same maven module as your productive code? If not they will not be considered covered when exercised by the tests.

Comment: What do you use for code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that all your tests are in error. Therefore, it is normal that the coverage is 0% because nothing is properly covered. Check the log to understand why all your tests are in error.